# LaunchOptions is always nil with SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, location, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

I have investigated siginificant location.
I would like to get location information when not running app.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service

The following code is an trigger for getting location information.

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if launchOptions?[.location] != nil {
            locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        }
        return true
    }
```

But I encountered  a strange behavior.
When an app launch by significant location event.

AppDelegate only: launchOptions?[.location] isn’t nil
AppDelegate + SceneDelegate: **launchOptions?[.location] is always nil**

I couldn’t get similar value from SceneDelegate method.

[SceneDelegate screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNu02.png)

If I want to use launchOptions related to location, is it better to use AppDelegate only?

Comment: In the screenshot you posted you need to step through one more line of code to see if `notificationResponse` is nil or not.

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` or `launchOptions?[.location]` is currently only available (as of iOS 7.4) with app delegate life-cycle that's when you remove your SceneDelegate class and remove the scene manifest from the Info.plist.

To get it with scene lifecycle you need to hack the info yourself, e.g. something like this:

**Info.plist**

```
Principal class = MyApplication
```

**YourApp-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "MyApplication.h"
```

**MyApplication.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface MyApplication: UIApplication

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL significantLocationCausedLaunch;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**MyApplication.m**

```
#import "MyApplication.h"

@interface UIApplication() // private methods

-(void)_connectUISceneFromFBSScene:(id)scene transitionContext:(id)context;

@end


@implementation MyApplication

- (void)_connectUISceneFromFBSScene:(UIScene *)scene transitionContext:(id)context {
    NSDictionary *payload = [context performSelector:@selector(payload)];
    self.significantLocationCausedLaunch = [[payload valueForKey:@"CLLaunchOptionsLocation"] boolValue];
    [super _connectUISceneFromFBSScene:scene transitionContext:context];
}

@end
```

Now you can retrieve it in your scene delegate as follows:

```
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        if let myApp = UIApplication.shared as? MyApplication {
            if myApp.significantLocationCausedLaunch {
                print("significantLocationCausedLaunch")
            }
        }
        
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
```

I reported this limitation of scene life cycle via Feedback for addition to SwiftUI as a `.backgroundTask(.significantLocation)` as [FB13699977](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5583288718589952) feel free to reference in your report.

Answer (score -1):

When you work with the scene delegate you should use `scene(:,willConnectTo session:,options:)` function instead

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene,
               willConnectTo session: UISceneSession,
               options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
// handle universal links
        if let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first {
            self.scene(scene, continue: userActivity)
        } else {
// handle other urls (f.e. your custom schemes)
            self.scene(scene, openURLContexts: connectionOptions.urlContexts)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that the OP has already tried using the scene delegate (see the screenshot posted in the question). The question is asking how to determine if the scene is being launched due to a location update.

Comment: In the attached screenshot breakpoint stands on the wrong line.

Comment: Yes, I made a comment about that below the question. My comment to your answer is that your answer is telling the OP to use the scene delegate but the OP has already try the scene delegate. And your code in the scene delegate has nothing to do with a location update. Given those two things, your answer doesn't solve the issue at all.